# What's a world for self-harming damage?

Tags: single-word-requests

Ex.

He threw the grenade, but it blew off part of his leg. He wasn't expecting any case of _______ damage, but that's what you get when you're reckless.

Is it "collateral" damage?

Comment: *Collateral*, although possible, does not necessarily mean damage to self.

Comment: How about saying that his plan **backfired**?

Answer (score 1):

Try [self-inflicted](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/self-inflicted)

He wasn't expecting any case of self-inflicted damage, but that's what you get when you're reckless.

Comment: I think self-inflicted suggests a voluntary action, while OP is describing an indicent.

Comment: @Josh61 Ya sure. But I think the need to have a word preponderates the source of action. Although he didn't wanna blow off his leg, it turned out to be so. So shouldn't it be "an incident of self-affliction?"

Answer (score 0):

I'd use ***[personal](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/personal):***

> - relating to your body or appearance.

- He wasn't expecting any case of personal damage.

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 0):

**suicidal**

Google's definition is:

> likely to have a disastrously damaging effect on oneself or one's interests.

Example:

> My friend dropped a grenade, and it was suicidal.